# Is it appropriate to use an example taken from a NSFW website in an answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

This answer on the UX Stack Exchange site uses part of a screenshot from a NSFW (pornography) website to answer the question: [Like/Dislike display order](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/111368/57109).

The image itself is obviously not of a sexual nature, but as "clearly" stated in the comments the screenshot was taken from a pornography website.

The only real problem I see here is the fact that the questioner, if desired, cannot visit the website to check-out/try-out the UX pattern because a link to the website can obviously not (and should not) be added.

Is this to be considered appropriate and allowed on the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: As long as it answers the question, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: As someone who dosen't watch porn...

I'd have no clue what the site is from the image.

Comment: I don't see why it would be impossible to check out the site. Adding a clickable link would be problematic, but not necessarily against the rules if there is adequate warning about the nature of the site. Alternatively, a slightly obfuscated link or simply the name of the website could be added to the post without any issue, and would allow the asker to find the real website.

Comment: Why you take so serious these things?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While we'd *prefer* that folks use examples that are 100% [safe for work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work), the fact that an example lives on a site that isn't safe to browse at work doesn't immediately disqualify an example from it as being inappropriate.

As long as the example is presented in a manner where:

- The part that answers the question is self-contained, you don't *need* to visit the site to see it.
- The answer clearly labels the site as not safe for work so that folks can make an informed choice of whether or not to go looking at the example in action
- Any parts of the answer on *our* sites are 100% safe for work

.. I don't see a major problem. That's not to say this can be a blanket answer, if an individual answer is found to be problematic despite making every attempt to follow these guidelines, it's going to be removed - so really do try to find 'SFW' examples :)

In short, if it doesn't create a problem, don't spend too much time looking for problems that might manifest. If such an answer became an issue later, it could easily be removed. If it does a helpful job of answering the question and isn't (itself) in any way offensive, I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Not official answer, just my own opinion as long time member: yes, this is appropriate.

What matters most is the content, not where it came from. If the content is correct and good, there should be no reason to not post it, except of course copyright matters, which I won't discuss here.

So assuming there is no copyright issue with sharing the content,  this should be just fine.

> the questioner, if desired, cannot visit the website to check-out/try-out the UX pattern

While this is true (also, many users are below 18 so can't enter such sites even provided a link), there are workarounds, for example if the user wants more details, they can ask the question author to provide them.

Comment: Don't get your last sentence? In a UX context, visiting the site would help to see the UX pattern discussed in action. That's why a link would be useful, not to copy the source code.

Comment: As the answer is on UX I would assume a link would be for testing usability patterns rather than inspecting any actual code

Comment: Hmm... will re-think this.